# How to read a binary file, readable in C, in Fortran

Tags: c, binary, fortran

I have a binary file that I can read with C with the following code

```
  int it,ix; 
  double par1,par2,par3,par4,par5,par6; 

  fp = fopen("my_binary_file", "r"); 
  assert(fp != NULL); 
  fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf \n",&it, &par1, &par2, &par3);
  fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf \n",&ix, &par4 ,&par5,&par6);
```

I tried reading the same file in Fortran 90 with this bit of code

```
  real(kind=8):: par1,par2,par3,par4,par5,par6
  integer :: it,ix

  open(1,file='my_binary_file',form='unformatted')

  read(1) it,par1,par2,par3
  read(1) ix,par4,par5,par6
```

But I get an End of file error. I tried reading the two lines together

```
  read(1) it,par1,par2,par3,ix,par4,par5,par6
```

I read something but the parameters are not what I expected. It means that I am reading the wrong bytes or that the declaration of the variables is wrong. Do you think you can help?

Comment: In your C example the parameters you pass to `fscanf` that start with '%' are format specifiers. In your FORTRAN code you are telling the compiler that what it is going to read is UNFORMATTED - you will need to work out what the correct FORTRAN format specifers are and supply them to the `open` command in your FORTRAN code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the C side

1) Your C binary file should have been opened as "rb" for a binary read.
2) fscanf is not used for reading binary files.  They are normally read using fread.
3) If it works, assume it is a text file

On the Fortran side,
4) Since it is a text file the form should be 'FORMATTED'.
5) After every read in Fortran, the file pointer moves to the next line.  This is not the same behaviour as in C.
6) Use the free format read to get the data if you don't wish to mess with format statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your C code doesn't look like reading what's usually called binary. If it were a C binary, you would have to use `STREAM` input, not `SEQUENTIAL`, which you implicitly use. Just try the normal formatted list-directed input.

```
open(10,file='my_binary_file')

read(10,*) it,par1,par2,par3
read(10,*) ix,par4,par5,par6
```

If there is more content in the file, show it.